# Laravel session::has('key') doesn't exist after new request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-7

First time working with Laravel and a bit confused.

Performing ajax request into controller action and after next request session key I've stored before doesn't exist.

The purpose of this code is to save some set of images and store their names to session for further work..

Session ID's equal in my parent page and ajax request. Application has no user authenticaton yet.

(Upd) Session driver is 'file' by default.

Why session key doesn't save normally?

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $rules = ['photo.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    $files = [];
    $fileNames = [];
    $errors = [];

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = ArrayHelper::getFinalValuesRecursive($validator->errors()->messages());
    } else {
        foreach ($request->file('photo') as $key => $value) {
            $imageName = $key . md5(time() . $key) . '.' . $value->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $value->move(public_path('uploads'), $imageName);

            $fileNames[] = $imageName;
            $files[] = '/uploads/' . $imageName;
        }

        $sessionFiles = [];

        if (Session::has('photo')) {
            $sessionPhoto = Session::get('photo');
            foreach ($sessionPhoto as $value) {
                $sessionFiles[] = $value;
            }
        }

        Session::put('photo', array_merge($sessionFiles, $fileNames));
    }
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#photo').on('change', function () {
        var fileData = $('#photo').prop('files');
        var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
            formData.append('photo[]', fileData[i]);
        }
        formData.append("_token", $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value')); //csrf

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route('adverts.upload')}}',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                response = $.parseJSON(response);

                if (response.errors.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.errors.length; i++) {
                        $('#image_errors')
                            .append('<div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">' + response.errors[i] + '</div>');
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#image_errors').html('');
                    var totalFile = response.files.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < totalFile; i++) {
                        $('#image_preview').append("<img src='" + response.files[i] + "'>");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: what is the uri for this route 'adverts.upload'?

Comment: URL is the same - /adverts/upload, I perform post request, there is no uri so query string is empty if this is what you mean

Comment: What are you usng for your session driver? ("file", "cookie", "database", "apc", "memcached", "redis", "array"). It will be set in your `.env` or `config.session.php`

Comment: @Spholt it is 'file' as default option, haven't changed anything.